# Comparing TextViews

Tags: java, android

This always returns the value of "else"...

```
   public void onClick(View view) {

            System.out.println("Palabra1= "+palabraDes.getText());
            System.out.println("Palabra2= "+palabraOrd.getText());

            String pla1 = palabraDes.getText().toString();
            String pla2 = palabraOrd.getText().toString();



            if (pla1 == pla2) {

                ttsManager.initQueue("Resultado correcto, buen trabajo.");

            } else

                ttsManager.initQueue("Incorrecto, intente de nuevo.");

        }
    });
```

Launching app:
I/System.out: Palabra1= perro
    Palabra2= perro

Comment: Instead of using `==` operator, you should use the `equals()` method when comparing objects e.g. `pla1.equals(pla2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `==` to compare strings. You will have to do `if (string1.equals(string2))`

```
   public void onClick(View view) {

        System.out.println("Palabra1= "+palabraDes.getText());
        System.out.println("Palabra2= "+palabraOrd.getText());

        String pla1 = palabraDes.getText().toString();
        String pla2 = palabraOrd.getText().toString();



        if (pla1.equals(pla2)) {

            ttsManager.initQueue("Resultado correcto, buen trabajo.");

        } else

            ttsManager.initQueue("Incorrecto, intente de nuevo.");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Equals() instead of ==

Answer (score 0):

Both `equals()` and `==` are used to compare objects to check for equality however the `==` checks if both objects point to the **same memory location** whereas `.equals()` evaluates **values in the objects**.

In your case you have to use `String.equals`

Replace

```
if (pla1 == pla2)
```

with

```
if (pla1.equals(pla2))
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when the text string passed, it came with a space (\ n), then all the forms worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot use == operator for strings

```
 Use if(pla1.equals(pla2))

    or

 Use if(pla1.equalsIgnoreCase(pla2))

 instead of if(pla1 == pla2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
if (pla1.equals(pla2)) {

   ttsManager.initQueue("Resultado correcto, buen trabajo.");

} else

   ttsManager.initQueue("Incorrecto, intente de nuevo.");
}
```

> **In general both equals() and “==” operator in Java are used to compare objects to check equality but here are some of the differences between the two:**
>
> Main difference between .equals() method and == operator is that one is method and other is operator.
>
> We can use **==** operators for reference comparison (address comparison) and **.equals()** method for content comparison.
>
> In simple words, **==** checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas .equals() evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.
>
> If a class does not override the equals method, then by default it uses equals(`Object o`) method of the closest parent class that has overridden this method.

I hope it will help you!